# Python pandas concatenate: join="inner" works on toy data, not on real data

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation

I'm working on topic modeling data where I have one data frame with a small selection of topics and their scores for each document or author (called "scores"), and another data frame with the top three words for all 250 topics (called "words").

I'm trying to combine the two data frames in a way to have an extra column in "scores", in which the top three words from "words" appear for each of the topics included in "scores". This is useful for visualizing the data as a heatmap, as `seaborn` or `pyplot` will pick up the labels automatically from such a dataframe.

I have tried a wide variety of merge and concat commands, but do not get the desired result. The strange thing is: what seems the most logical command, according to my understanding of the relevant documentation and the examples there (i.e. use `concat` on the two df with `axis=1` and `join="inner"`), works on toy data but does not work on my real data.

Here is my toy data with the code I used to generate it and to do the merge:

```
import pandas as pd

## Defining the two data frames
scores = pd.DataFrame({'author1': ['1.00', '1.50'],
                    'author2': ['2.75', '1.20'],
                    'author3': ['0.55', '1.25'],
                    'author4': ['0.95', '1.3']},
                     index=[1, 3])                     

words = pd.DataFrame({'words': ['cadavre','fenêtre','musique','mariage']},
                     index=[0, 1, 2, 3])

## Inspecting the two dataframes
print("\n==scores==\n", scores)
print("\n==words==\n", words)

## Merging the dataframes
merged = pd.concat([scores, words], axis=1, join="inner")

## Check the result
print("\n==merged==\n", merged)
```

And this is the output, as expected:

```
==scores==
   author1 author2 author3 author4
1    1.00    2.75    0.55    0.95
3    1.50    1.20    1.25     1.3

==words==
      words
0  cadavre
1  fenêtre
2  musique
3  mariage

==merged==
   author1 author2 author3 author4    words
1    1.00    2.75    0.55    0.95  fenêtre
3    1.50    1.20    1.25     1.3  mariage
```

This is exactly what I would like to accomplish with my real data. And although the two dataframes seem no different from the test data, I get an empty dataframe as the result of the merge.

Here are is a small example from my real data:

someScores (complete table):

```
      blanche  policier
108  0.003028  0.017494
71   0.002997  0.016956
115  0.029324  0.016127
187  0.004867  0.017631
122  0.002948  0.015118
```

firstWords (first 5 rows only; the index goes to 249, all index entries in "someScores" have an equivalent in "firstwords"):

```
                               topicwords
0              château-pays-intendant (0)
1                 esclave-palais-race (1)
2                  linge-voisin-chose (2)
3          question-messieurs-réponse (3)
4        prince-princesse-monseigneur (4)
5               arbre-branche-feuille (5)
```

My merge command:

```
dataToPlot = pd.concat([someScores, firstWords], axis=1, join="inner")
```

And the resulting data frame (empty)!

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [blanche, policier, topicwords]
Index: []
```

I have tried many variants, like using `merge` instead or creating extra columns replicating the indexes and then merging on those with `left_on` and `right_on`, but then I either get the same result or I just get NaN in the "topicwords" column.

Any hints and help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There are no matching values in your indices hence the empty concatenated df, does the index matter for `someScores`?

Comment: The data frame `firstWords` has 250 rows with an index from 0 to 249 (only 0-5 shown here), so there should be a matching value. The index in `someScores` matters because these are specific topics. Also, their order matters (they are sorted by decreasing standard deviation across rows and should appear in this order in the heatmap.)

Comment: What is the dtype of the indices? It looks like one may be int or str? Can you show the output from `type(df.index)` for both dfs this may explain why they don't match

Comment: Yes, they seem different dtypes: `dtype firstWords:  <class 'pandas.core.index.Int64Index'>`and `dtype someScores:  <class 'pandas.core.index.Index'>`. What can I do about this?

Comment: You can try casting `someScores.index = someScores.index.astype(np.int64)` and then join

Comment: This works! I get good values for "intersection" and the merged dataframe also looks good. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inner join only returns rows whose index is present in both dataframes.
Consider your row indices for `someScores` ( *108 71 115 187 122* ) and `firstWords` ( *0 1 2 3 4 5* ) contain no common value in row index the resultant is an empty dataframe.

Either set these indeces correctly or specify different criteria for joining.
You can confirm the problem by checking for common values in both index

```
someScores.index.intersection(firstWords.index)
```

For different strategies of joining refer [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html).

Comment: I wish that were the reason. Please see my comment above (and the explanation in front of `firstWords`in my question. The dataframe `firstWords` goes from 0 to 249 and has entries for each of 108, 71, 115, 187, 122.

Comment: Just as an example, the result of `print(firstWords.iloc[118,:]` is: `topicwords    amour-bras-baiser (118)`, so that does not seem the issue.

Comment: Could you also check the output of `someScores.index.intersection(firstWords.index)` share the number of common values in both indices

Comment: Thanks for this idea! We are getting closer, there is indeed something wrong here regarding the intersection. On the toy data, I get `Int64Index([1, 3], dtype='int64')` and on the real data `Index([], dtype='object')`. I'm wondering why that is so.

Comment: EdChum suggested recasting the index of `someScores` to get the same dtype. After that, intersection was fine and `concat` worked. Thank you!